# how to implement "Directory.GetAccessControl(directory)" in .net standard 2.0

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, .net-framework-version, .net-standard-2.0

currently the solution contain both .net standrd and .net framework code

```
Directory.GetAccessControl("<file path>").GetAccessRules(true, true, typeof(System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier))
```

the above piece of code is there in .net framework , but it is notworking in .net standad
i have tried by implementing this

```
(new DirectoryInfo("<file path>")).GetAccessControl().GetAccessRules(true, true, typeof(System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier));
```

while runtime it gives error the "**System.IO.FileSystem.AccessControl**" is not getting loading

Comment: Support for this is not included natively in any version of Standard (as it's very specific to Windows), but is offered by the [`System.IO.FileSystem.AccessControl` package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.IO.FileSystem.AccessControl/). You'll then need to go through either `FileInfo` or `DirectoryInfo`, depending on the kind of path.

Comment: while using  FileInfo or DirectoryInfo- (ex: -(new DirectoryInfo("<file path>")).GetAccessControl()) in runtime i am getting an exception like "Could not load file or assembly 'System.IO.FileSystem.AccessControl, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified"         could you please help me on this @JeroenMostert.

Comment: That likely happens because you're using the library wrong. Using it requires that you either reference it from another project in a solution, or that you build the library itself as a NuGet package and reference that. If you use any other way (by simple copy-pasting files for example, or by referencing only the final .dll directly) the system can't fix up the dependencies correctly, as this differs between the platform used for your executable.

Comment: yes i have taken the library form nuget package "<PackageReference Include="System.IO.FileSystem.AccessControl" Version="5.0.0"/>" . so because of this i getting the exception ? or is there any other library is present which i can use to fix this issue ? could  you please suggest @JeroenMostert

Comment: No, you're getting it because the library *you* build ends up getting used wrong. The reference in your library itself is not the problem, this is necessary to get things to build. The error you're getting should be happening at *runtime*, not at *compile time*, correct? If you're getting it at compile time, try cleaning your project, restarting VS and rebuilding things.

Comment: correct @JeroenMostert i am getting the error in runtime not in compile time.

Comment: Then I refer you back to my earlier comment; build your executable correctly and refer to your library correctly, because that's not happening now. A simple test on my end where I create a .NET Core console application and refer to the library in the same solution works. If you intend to distribute your library for use by multiple applications for different frameworks, you'll need to build it as a NuGet package.

Comment: Hi @JeroenMostert i have tried it with .net core solution it got work for me will it work for .net framework solution which contain an .net standard app, coz i have tried with .net framework and it didn't work for me